# Priorities in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I want my test cases to execute priority wise, but all the test cases which depends on 'Method1' are executing first, so my other testcases are failing.

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"verifyLogin"}, priority = 0, description = "verify a page access")

  public void Method1()
```

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"Method1"}, priority = 1, description = "verify b page access")

```
  public void Method2() 

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"Method1"}, priority = 2, description = "verify c page access")

  public void Method3()

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"Method3"}, priority = 3, description = "verify d page access")

  public void Method4()

 @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"Method1"}, priority = 4, description = "verify e page access")

  public void Method5()
```

So the methods 1,2,3 and 5 are executing first, but I want method 4 to execute before 5 as it depends on method 3.

Thanks.

Comment: Why use both test dependencies _and_ priorities?

Comment: Anyway; drop the priorities in your test parameters and only leave method dependencies. There is no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Hey fge, I used priorities, just to make my class more understandable that which test case is executing first, if I don't use it, the test cases will still execute in the same manner from top to bottom. I think method dependencies doesn't have their own priorities and it depends on us when we want to execute dependent methods by giving them priorities. I'm still not sure why this issue is arising.

Comment: Uh, TestNG does not guarantee an execution order _unless_ you use `dependsOnMethods` or `priority`, and it will execute all tests unless a dependency is not satistifed; I don't get your point.

Comment: Ummm, can you edit my above code so I can understand easily. I have method4 which is dependent on method3, so its dependonmethod = method3. I want this method to execute before method 5 which depends on method1. Always method5 executes before method4 which I want. How can I do it? :(

Comment: Does this mean that method5 actually depends on method4?

Comment: Oh sorry, typo..Always method5 executes before method4 which I don't want. How can I do it?

Comment: method 4 depends on method 3 and method 5 depends on method 1. I want method 4 to execute before method 5. How can I do it? Method 5 always executes before method 4 which I don't want.

Comment: But _why do you care_? If you care, it means that method5 depends on method4

Comment: I removed some dependencies and now it is working fine. Thanks fge for your help. I don't know exactly what the issue is when I'm using dependsonmethod with priorities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced similar problem in my framework test classes. usually if we use both `dependsOnMethods` or `priority` in our test class testng executes test with priority first but doesn't apply priority to tests having `dependsOnMethods`. Tests with 'dependsOnMethod' attribute will run in the last as per their dependencies/priorities. Test case execution order will be like below:

1. Test cases without dependencies according to priorities.
2. Test case with dependencies in order of test methods they are dependent on and priority.

Hence,In your case it will execute test cases having dependency on 'method1' first and than test case having dependency on 'method3'. To solve this problem you need understand in which sequence you tests are going to executed based on `priorities` and `dependsOnMethods`. You have to adjust both attributes accordingly. You can also make one test case dependent on multiple test methods for example in your case you can make test case 4 dependent on 'method1' as well as 'method3'.